# Android: how to catch remote image loading failure

Tags: android, android-imageview

I have to update my  with a remote image, in case of any failure/timeout, I have to restore it with a local default image.

Here is my code snippet:

```
try{
headerLogoView.setImageDrawable(remoteURL);
}catch(Exception e) {
Log.e(Constants.LOGTAG, CLASSTAG+": updateViews(): Exception: "+e.getMessage());
headerLogoView.setImageResource(R.drawable.logo);
}
```

But it is not working. can anybody plz help me.

Thanks,
Nehatha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to load the image from the network in a background thread and only set the image if that operation succeeds. You can use AsyncTask for this. Don't use setImageUri as it will cause your application to not respond if there are issues loading the image.